# Calculate a difference measure in Power BI based on two selected dates

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, data-transform

At the moment I'm calculating a measure, which desribes the value-difference between a report date and the day before the selected report date. That means, if a user select today, then it shows the difference between the actual day and yesterday of that value. The report date can be selected by the user up to two years in the past.

[image]

The value difference is calculated as the following:

```
diffValue = SUM(table2[value])-[yesterdayValue]
```

The `yesterdayValue` is calculated like this:

```
yesterdayValue = 
var SelDate = SELECTEDVALUE(table1[valuationtime])
var PrevDate = CALCULATE(MAX(table1[valuationtime]), FILTER(ALL(table1), table1[valuationtime] < SelDate))
var result = CALCULATE(SUM(table2[value]), REMOVEFILTERS(table1[valuationtime]), table1[valuationtime] = PrevDate)
return result
```

This gives me the daily difference between a report date that was preselected at any time.

Now I would prefer to adapt the whole thing and give the user two dates to select. On the one hand, the report date as before and, on the other hand, the reference date (at the moment this is the day before the report date in my calculation). The user would therefore have two date selections in front of them and receive the difference in the value between the report date and the reference date. Both date selections access the same column of a table.

How can I solve this problem?

**EDIT:** Here you can see the two tables and how they connected:
[image]

**table1:**

[image]

table2 has the same valuationtime-column.

Comment: Can you update the question with a more info on `table1` and `table2`, what are they, how are they connected? I'm asking as currently you will need to have a Date/Calendar table. Also are the dates in `table1[valuationtime]` contiguous?

Comment: I have made some edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need to have a separate "date" table for your second slicer.  Create a new Calculate Table with:

```
table1 (ref) = 'table1'
```

Decide if you need to add any relationships to other tables, but you don't need one to `table2`.

Then have these measures:

```
Report value = SUM(table2[value])


Reference value = 
  var refDate = DISTINCT( 'table1 (ref)'[valuationtime] )
  return
    CALCULATE(
      [Report value],
      REMOVEFILTERS('table1'),
      'table2'[valuationtime] IN refDate
    )


DiffValue = [Report value] - [Reference value]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have adapted my model and use now your measures. Unfortunately, when I switch between different ``reference dates``, then the value differences stay always the same, which can't be correct. Where is the connection to the selected reference date? I can't see this. When defining ``var refDate`` then ``refDate`` is chosen to be the maximum of ``valuationtime``.  But here ``refDate`` should be chosen by a PowerBI User, and it is not always the maximum?! Should we adapt this with something like ``SELECTEDVALUE()``?

Comment: The problem with `SELECTEDVALUE()` is that it will return blank if more than one value is found. `MAX()` is better here as if more than one value is found, it will take the largest one. For example, if the slicer was `currentYearIC` and the user selects 2023, then `SELECTEDVALUE('table1 (ref)'[valuationtime])` will return blank, whereas `MAX()` will return the latest/largest date for 2023. Have you created a duplicate table (`table1 (ref)`)? Share a link to a sample PBIX and will happily have a look.

Comment: I've also updated the answer to use `DISTINCT` and `IN`. See if that is better now.

Comment: Also with ``DISTINCT()`` and ``IN`` the problem isn't sloved. Again, I get the same values for each ``reference date`` selection. So the calculation of the ``difference value`` doesn't work here for each selected day. When I select ``reference date`` and ``report date`` the same, then I should get a ``difference value = 0``, but it is not the case.

Comment: Can you share a link to a sample PBIX?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot share the report since it is a company report, and I work within the company's workspace. How can we work around this? How can I provide you with sample tables?

Comment: Here, have a look at: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtpcKzRsDrY1o7xnF2p5qk30HrX9hA?e=ffOgoI

Comment: I cannot open this link. Sorry.

Comment: Why? Broken link? What do you see?

Comment: I see OneDrive and a pbix-file to download. But I cannot download this pbix-file and I also cannot click something on this page/website.

Comment: Can you share a screen grab of that page? There should be a download link at the top left tool bar.

Comment: This work for the difference between today and yesterday:``yesterdayDifference = 
    var SelDate = SELECTEDVALUE(table1[valuationtime])
    var PrevDate = CALCULATE(MAX(table1[valuationtime]), FILTER(ALL(table1), table1[valuationtime] < SelDate))
    var result = CALCULATE(SUM(table2[value]), REMOVEFILTERS(table1[valuationtime]), table1[valuationtime] = PrevDate)
return result``.  Can we adapt this one to something where the reference date can be selected?

Comment: Not really, the objective is to capture the 2nd slicer (ie user selected date).

Comment: I thought we could simply choose the second slicer using ``SELECTEDVALUE()`` like this: 
 ``var SelDate = SELECTEDVALUE(table1 (ref)[valuationtime])``

Comment: If it works then go for it 

Comment: No unfortunately it doesn't work. But also your version of calculating the difference between two selected dates doesn't work in my case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256935/discussion-between-sam-nseir-and-mikik).